# R error in bioconductor package installation

Tags: r, installation, package, bioconductor

I am experiencing a problem to install the `snpMatrix` package (ftp://ctan.uib.no/pub/bioconductor/2.7/bioc/html/snpMatrix.html).

After using the below command:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("snpMatrix")
```

I got this error:

```
BioC_mirror: http://bioconductor.org
Using Bioconductor version 3.1 (BiocInstaller 1.18.4), R version 3.2.2.
Installing package(s) ‘snpMatrix’
Warning message:
package ‘snpMatrix’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)
```

Any ideas to solve this problem in package installation? Are you experiencing the same error? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, same problem for me )ubuntu 14.04, R3.2.2). Have you tried insyalling from source http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.3/bioc/html/snpMatrix.html

Comment: `snpMatrix` is not available for Bioconductor 3.1, try installing version Bioconductor 2.1, then install `snpMatrix`... not sure if this is possible.